# Scam Shapeshift site

Tags: shapeshift

Looks like I have been scammed by the fake Shapeshifter site, it was a substantial amount, 69 Monero.

It was the google search result of Shapeshift.com not Shapeshift.io

This is really going to hurt my family, is there ANY way of finding these Moneros or are they lost forever?

Comment: Doesn't shapeshift.com redirect to shapeshift.io?

Comment: It seems to now when I try to load the fake page.

Comment: This happened about a week ago. I received an initial reply from Shapeshift that I used an invalid payment ID and they asked for a return address. I provided that then last night they emailed me saying that I had used the fake site, which I guess they saw from my screen shots I sent.

Comment: Does anyone have ANY idea if there is a way to track down the funds and have them returned or are they lost forever?

Comment: If you sent your moneroj to the wrong address and you don't know who owns that address, there is no way to track them or to cancel the transaction I'm afraid.

Comment: I knew that might be the case, but thought I’d ask anyway.